# Samba. Writable for two or more users

Tags: samba

Have user1 and user2. They are in usergroup1.

in console run it:

```
sudo chgrp -R usergroup1 /folder
```

Lihe this - https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileprint-security.html > Share Security.

In smb.conf

```
[folder]
comment = folder
path = /folder
browsable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = no
write list = user1, user2
create mask = 0777
```

But only user2 can create/delete files.

I think it because before that I run in console:

```
sudo chown -R user2 /folder
```

How set folder writable for both users?

Also I try

```
write list = user1 user2
```

Without a comma. But so does not work.

**UPD**

I try change owner like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown

```
chown -R :usergroup1 /folder
```

And edit smb.conf like this

```
write list = @usergroup1
```

But still both users can't add/del file in /folder.

**UPD2 - Solution**

I can cunfig it! Hope it help somebody.

smb.conf

```
[folder]
comment = folder
path = /folder
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0770
directiory mask = 0770
valid users = @usergroup1
```

And mod for folder

```
chmod 775 /folder
```

Comment: Please post the solution in the answer box below, so this question shows up as answered!

Answer (score 1):

ok.. let's try this..

parent folder (`chmod 777 / chown nobody:nogroup -R`)

- Folder1 (`chmod 770 / chown nobody:group1 -R`)
- Folder2 (`chmod 770 / chown nobody:group2 -R`)

  useradd user1 group1
  useradd user2 group2

at samba...

```
[group1]
guest ok = no (or yes you must check this)
force user = nobody
force group = group1
writelist = user1 @group1
read list = user2 @group2
```

same for the [group2] but change the order os users at write and read...

bye!